# Mobius band does not retract to boundary circle - specific part

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

(I'm trying to ask this in a way such that it isn't a duplicate question)

The proofs that I've seen for the fact that there is no retraction from the Mobius band to its boundary circle usually say that the homomorphism induced by inclusion is multiplication by 2, or they contradict the fact that the induced homomorphism from the retraction is surjective.

My problem is, at some point they talk about the fundamental group of the core circle as it sits inside of the Mobius band and do so ostensibly without worrying about basepoints.  The basic idea is that one loop "wraps twice around another" - but the loops have different basepoints.

I guess the question then is, taking $M$ to be the mobius band, $\partial M$ to be its boundary and assuming we have a retraction $r$ gets us $r\circ i=1_{\partial M}$ where $i$ is inclusion.  To account for basepoints, write $r:(M,x_0)\to (\partial M, y_0)$ and $i:(\partial M,x_0)\to (M, x_0)$; how do you write this up?  Presumably you would trace a generator $[g]$ of $\pi_1(\partial M, x_0)$ through the commuting triangle given by $(1_{\partial M})_*=(r\circ i)_*$?  I know that $i_*([g])$ can be explicitly computed, and there is a deformation retraction from $M$ to its core circle $C$.

Comment: You can always compose with some explicit isomorphism between fundamental groups with different basepoints.

Comment: You can use 1st homology if you are bothered by base points so much.

Comment: It might be something so simple I'm unsure of how to write it down: e.g. 'explicit isomorphism between fundamental groups'?  I wouldn't doubt the existence of such an isom, but what do I do with it?  Usually solutions eventually involve the core circle of the Mobius band, but I'm having trouble "fitting" that in, so to speak, into the "usual" solution to retraction existence problems.  [Homology requires much more background than this, but is itself wonderful]

Comment: What book are you using? Any reasonable textbook will explain how to get _explicit_ isomorphisms $\pi_1(X,x)\to \pi_1(X,y)$ for path-connected topological spaces $X$. In your case, $X$ is the Moebius band and $x$ is on its boundary while $y$ is in the core circle.

Comment: Replace the boundary circle with the union of the boundary circle and a line segment extending from that circle out to the basepoint inside the core circle. The argument goes exactly the same because this space deformation retracts onto the boundary circle, but now we have both spaces sharing a basepoint.

Comment: An attempt:  Let $g$ be the loop in $\partial M$ that goes around $\partial M$ once, starting at $x_0$.  Then consider $g':=i_*([g])$. Note, $M$ deformation retracts to its core circle $C$.  Let $r_2$ be the retraction corresponding to this deformation retraction.  Then $(r_2)_*$ is an isomorphism that takes $g'$ to the element in $\pi_1(C,r_2(x_0))$ that corresponds to 2.  But $(r_2)_*$ is an isomorphism, so $g'$ corresponds to 2.  Which is a contradiction since we can calculate $g'$ directly from $i_*$. QED Seems you compute $g'$ in two different ways.  Is this correct?